# How to split the array of object to create a new object

Tags: javascript

I have an array with multiple objects.So how to make a new object by splitting the objects.

Here is how i am doing manually. How can I achieve it dynamically.

```js
var a ='["{\\"Transfer_Notes__c\\":{\\"filterType\\":\\"text\\",\\"type\\":\\"contains\\",\\"filter\\":\\"abc\\"}}","{\\"IQ_Score__c\\":{\\"filterType\\":\\"number\\",\\"type\\":\\"equals\\",\\"filter\\":null,\\"filterTo\\":null}}"]';
var c = {};
c= JSON.parse(a);
const obj = Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(c[0]),JSON.parse(c[1]));


console.log(obj)
```

I tried several ways. Please help!

Comment: You have double-encoded JSON. Your parsed array contains JSON strings, not objects

Comment: Try using a loop `(for const item of c) { ... // Your code here}`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That's why you see multiple calls to `JSON.parse()` What a I missing, how does your comment have two upvotes? Did you run the code?

Comment: That doesn't make it anymore sensible @JuanMendes

Comment: @Liam Sometimes you don't have control over what you're given

Comment: Try: `c= JSON.parse(a).map(s => JSON.parse(s))`

Comment: @Titus that will parse all the inner JSONs, but the OP wants a single object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var a ='["{\\"Transfer_Notes__c\\":{\\"filterType\\":\\"text\\",\\"type\\":\\"contains\\",\\"filter\\":\\"abc\\"}}","{\\"IQ_Score__c\\":{\\"filterType\\":\\"number\\",\\"type\\":\\"equals\\",\\"filter\\":null,\\"filterTo\\":null}}"]';
var c = JSON.parse(a);
const obj = c.reduce((obj, c) => Object.assign(obj, JSON.parse(c)), {});

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a reviver function with `JSON.parse()` to specify that the array values should also be parsed. Then you can spread the parsed objects from the array into a resulting object using `Object.assign()`:

```js
var a ='["{\\"Transfer_Notes__c\\":{\\"filterType\\":\\"text\\",\\"type\\":\\"contains\\",\\"filter\\":\\"abc\\"}}","{\\"IQ_Score__c\\":{\\"filterType\\":\\"number\\",\\"type\\":\\"equals\\",\\"filter\\":null,\\"filterTo\\":null}}"]';

const parsed = JSON.parse(a, (key, val) => key ? JSON.parse(val) : val);
const c = Object.assign({}, ...parsed);
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var a ='["{\\"Transfer_Notes__c\\":{\\"filterType\\":\\"text\\",\\"type\\":\\"contains\\",\\"filter\\":\\"abc\\"}}","{\\"IQ_Score__c\\":{\\"filterType\\":\\"number\\",\\"type\\":\\"equals\\",\\"filter\\":null,\\"filterTo\\":null}}"]';
var c = {};
c= JSON.parse(a);
const A ={};
var obj = {};
for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++){
  obj = Object.assign(A, JSON.parse(c[i]),);
}



console.log(obj)
```

Please suggest if there is any alternative way; Suggest me if i am doing wrong

Comment: Almost ideal, but you have logic mistake - you assign each string for new empty object, and final result contains only last string. Fix that - `obj = Object.assign(obj, JSON.parse(c[i]));` and your code will work

Comment: You can see from the output that you're only getting a single property, that's because you need to write to the same object when calling `Object.assign`. Right now, you're overwriting the object with every write

Comment: @SFKID This should be part of your question, not an answer. Please do not post an answer when you are actually asking a question, unless you know for sure that your answer is correct. https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @JuanMendes Check it now.

Comment: @SFKID Please don't ignore my comment and then ask me for my help